# How to access data member values in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

Following is my WCF code-

```
public class Detect : IDetect
{
   [DataMember]
   string landMark1, landMark2, landMark3;
   [DataMember]
   int pingCounter;

   public void setLandMark(string lm1, string lm2, string lm3)
   {
      landMark1 = lm1;
      landMark2 = lm2;
      landMark3 = lm3;
   }

   public void setPingCounter(int p)
   {
      pingCounter = p;
   }
}
```

When I debug my code and access setLandMark() it assigns the parameters passed by client object to the private data member of the class, but when I call the other function setPingCounter() it shows the landmark data members as null.

suppose following is my code for client side-

```
DetectClient proxy = new DetectClient();
proxy.setLandMark("google.com", "yahoo.com", "facebook.com");
proxy.setPingCounter(5);
```

When setPingCounter is called landmark1, landmark2, landmark3 are initialized to null. I guess every call to method initiates different client object. If is it so, how can I avoid this?

Comment: Too many answers here. Can you provide more information about how you assign and call ypur properties?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: You don't have to mark the `private` member as `DataContract`, just member you will expose, `public` members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you creating WCF service? If so, you probably forget to apply right **ServiceBehavior** attribute to your service implementation. By default it will create service for each request to its contract.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Add this to your *Detect* service implementation and your service will be single for every request to contract.